# WPF control with navigation capability

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have something like 15 grids and I want to put them in on one control with some kind of navigation ... something like tabs panel but instead of tabs I would like to have arrow or page number.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all the (15) grids in a `List<Grid>` gridList. Create a `ContentControl` and put first item of `gridList` as `content` of `ContentControl`. Provide buttons(arrow) for forward and back. On the arrow button click change the content of `ContentControl` based on which button (forward or backward) has been clicked by selecting appropriate Grid from the gridList.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx) with several [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.aspx) objects - you will get Next and Previous controls, history and more for free.

[Creating navigation based applications in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaps_deo/Navigation_Based_Application04052009135219PM/Navigation_Based_Application.aspx).